# how to get courses created by particular user in moodle 3

Tags: moodle

Currently I'm working on moodle-3 plug-in development,and I have a user Id who is a course creator and i want to get all courses created by that user,is their any function, I can use or if you can help me with names of tables where I can fetch this data.I tried table called standard log where I can get all events is that only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work but you could try searching for courses that have the coursecreator role assigned.

```
SELECT r.shortname, u.username, c.fullname AS coursename
FROM mdl_role r
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.roleid = r.id
JOIN mdl_context ctx ON ctx.id = ra.contextid AND ctx.contextlevel = 50
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = ra.userid
WHERE r.shortname = 'coursecreator'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,please can you tel me why is contextlevel is used.

Comment: Context is used for user permissions - https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Context - contextlevel = 50 is the course level

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot